# Xamarin cross form, authentification sqlite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am very new to Xamarin . I am looking for a way to create an authentication form page and then put my slqite data in a server.

I have already managed to create my sqlite database model and managed to put data (in this instance names of cars) into the database.

Here is my xaml form, this is presented to a user when they want to create an account and it is identical for log in:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="20">

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="2" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="Connect !" FontSize="25"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <Label Text="Name" FontSize="25"/>
            <Entry x:Name="MyName" Placeholder="Your Name please" ></Entry>

            <Label Text="Adress Mail" FontSize="25"/>
            <Entry x:Name="Mymail" Placeholder="Your Adress mail please"></Entry>

            <Label Text="Profession" FontSize="25"/>
            <Entry x:Name="MyProfession" Placeholder="Your Profession please" ></Entry>

            <Label Text="Your Password" FontSize="25"/>
            <Entry IsPassword="true" x:Name="MyPassword" Placeholder="your password please" FontSize="Medium"></Entry>    

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Text="OK" BackgroundColor="Gray" TextColor="White"   FontSize="25"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Ideally I'm looking for easy to follow examples of how to implement this kind of pattern, If you have any sample code for each step that would also be really useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there are already dozens, if not hundreds, of tutorials on working with webservices and remote databases.

Comment: Can you give me an example please

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/